# AWS API Gateway - Can I change base_mapping for custom domain name without interrupting clients?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am running lambda function and api gateway with custom domain name.

And I want to change base mapping for custom domain with other api gateway deployment.

Can I change base_mapping for custom domain name without interrupting connected clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All updates to API Gateway, whether deploying to a stage or modifying a basepath, are 0 downtime operations. In flight requests are serviced with the old configuration until the given service host receives the updated configuration. Depending on the region, this can take a few seconds to apply to all API Gateway service hosts.